# How to set check box to be unchecked

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have some trouble with setting a checkbox to be unchecked.
I have two fragments, first fragment contains a checkbox and a button, after I check the check box and press the next button, second fragments loads and displays a message. When I press back button, the first fragment reloads and the checkbox remains checked, how can I make it to be unchecked.

Here's how I initialize the checkbox, this function is called from onViewCreated()

```
private void initRefundCheckBox(){

        final CheckBox refund = getView().findViewById(R.id.refund_checkbox);

        if(isRefund)//This section is to check if we reloaded the first 
                    //pragment and isRefund was already true - then set it 
                    //to be false and uncheck the checkbox
        {
            isRefund = false;
            refund.toggle();
            refund.setSelected(isRefund);
            refund.setChecked(isRefund);
        }
        refund.setChecked(isRefund);
        refund.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                isRefund = refund.isChecked();
                /// somecode

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: how you added second fragment?

Comment: persist state of checkBox in SharedPreferences . look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261296/how-to-save-a-checkbox-state-in-android-app

Comment: have updated the code update if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, after you start the second fragment on onClickListener of the nextButton, reset the checkbox.

```
refund.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: what if he checked it and then come back again by pressing the back button. it will make it unChecked.... I don't know how he accepted it as answer. may be he is not aware of all scenarios

Comment: @ZaidMirza he said in the question **When I press back button, the first fragment reloads and the checkbox remains checked, how can I make it to be unchecked.** 
i think you missed this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

`Override` a function in the first fragment .. `setUserVisibilityHint(...)` in there just set the check to false.. like this..

```
 @Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (getActivity()!=null)
    {

        refund.setChecked(false);


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't help.

Comment: why what was the problem with this? @Keselme

Comment: It just didn't have any effect on the program the behaviour remained the same. The checkbox was still checked.

Comment: @Keselme how did you reload the fragment ? transaction ?

Comment: I use getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();

Comment: Is this method supposed to be called automatically or should I call it myself? While debugging I never reach it.

Comment: it is automatically called.. you dont need to call it... it might be your `getActivity() == null`

Comment: I don't think it because of the activity, because I don't even reach the if statement.