# How to save checkbox State in other activity

Tags: android, sql, listview, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

In this MainActivity.java I am trying to call a checkbox which is in other layout.
Purpose: I want to save the state of the `CheckBox` even when the activity is closed it should the state of the `CheckBox.`
If someone of you have different method for adding the `CheckBox` in the `ListView` please add that code. I am trying to make a todo list app.

```
package com.vivekraja07.vivekatgt;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast; 

import com.vivekraja07.vivekatgt.db.Task;
import com.vivekraja07.vivekatgt.db.TaskHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private TaskHelper mHelper;
private ListView mTaskListView;

private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mHelper = new TaskHelper(this);

    CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    boolean checked = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .getBoolean("checkBox", false);
    checkBox1.setChecked(checked);
    mTaskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_todo);
    mTaskListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    updateUI();
}
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkBox:
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
                    .putBoolean("checkBox", checked).commit();
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add_task:
            final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("New Task")
                    .setMessage("Add a new task")
                    .setView(taskEditText)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogue, int which) {
                            String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                            if (task.length() == 0) {
                                return;
                            }
                            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.put(Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, task);
                            db.insertWithOnConflict(Task.TaskEntry.TABLE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                            db.close();
                            updateUI();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .create();
            dialog.show();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_delete:
            Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.menu_item_select:
            Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}

private void updateUI() {
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Task.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            new String[] {Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE}, null, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(index));
    }

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_todo, R.id.task_title, taskList);
        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}

public void deleteTask(View view) {
    View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    TextView taskTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    taskTextView.setPaintFlags(taskTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    db.close();
    updateUI();

}
}
```

here is the code for item_todo.xml from where the Checkbox is called.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/task_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:text="Hi"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:onClick="deleteTask"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check the code i have already used it but it is not recognizing the checkbox through id

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162920/cannot-convert-java-lang-string-into-json-object @Rumit patel please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preference to save any data using key value pair. The state of the checkbox ca be save in the shared preference and access it throught the key. Check out this post for the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25261571/6836165).

Comment: check my code i have already added this but it is not recognizing the checkbox in that example the checkbox was in  main activity . Suggest the whole code and i will copy it and try to run it.

Comment: in layout onclick in checkbox you have called 'deleteTask', change it to 'onCheckboxClicked' and in activity make boolean checked global... that should do the trick.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162920/cannot-convert-java-lang-string-into-json-object @Bwes please help

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the state of the checkbox in SharedPreferences like this. Add a onCheckedChangeListener and save the state there:

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

 @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
 boolean isChecked) {
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
                    .putBoolean("checkBox", isChecked).commit();
 }

 })
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162920/cannot-convert-java-lang-string-into-json-object @deluxe1 please help